# Is there a way to check if any natural odd number can be represented in this form?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, number-theory

How to prove/disprove that any natural odd number greater than or equal to 9, can be represented in this form.

$$ \frac{2^{x+3} + 1}{3^y} $$ where $ x, y \in Z+ $ (positive integers).

eg:

- 9 can be when (0, 0)
- 11 is when (2, 1)

I do understand that it's probably not an easy problem to solve, but any approaches that I could try would also help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $2^{x+3} + 1$ can never be an integral multiple of $7$.

Comment: Similarly, you can't get any multiple of $23$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given an odd $x$ there is an $m,n$ such that $2^n + 1 = 3^m x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232634/given-an-odd-x-there-is-an-m-n-such-that-2n-1-3m-x) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B2%5Ex%2B1%7D%7B3%5Ey%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1).

Comment: I wish I could understand what the answer means @JohnOmielan

Comment: The answer in that question, does it mean its true that Given any odd x ... ?

Comment: @vishnusatis The result is that it's *not* always true for any given odd $x$, with the other question's answer giving various examples & conditions where there are no solutions. Also, my and lulu's comments above give a couple of specific examples, i.e., odd multiples of $7$ (greater than $9$ to meet your restriction) and odd multiples of $23$.